# shell script to print and sort the date column in csv

Tags: shell, csv

I have a large csv file having the date column at column number 4 of csv file
the format of data is format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.0000000 +11:30 
I want to sort this date in ascending order and dump it into the another csv file container top 10 entries or print.

I have tried with the following command:

```
sort -t, nk4 file.csv >/tmp/s.csv
```

Comment: Just a note: the sort will fail to sort by time when the timezones (`+11:30`) are different...  you need convert the times to `UTC` before sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `sort -t, -nk4` (`-` is missing before options).

To output only the 10 first lines, you can pipe your `sort` to `head`:

```
sort -t, -nk4 file.csv | head -n10 > /tmp/s.csv
```

The same maybe a bit more readable:

```
sort -t ","  -k 4 -n file.csv | head -n10 > /tmp/s.csv
```

`head -n10` is to print only the 10 first line of the `sort` output.

Comment: i think u mean same:       sort -t, -nk4 file.csv | head -n1 >/tmp/s.csv

Comment: For 10 first lines, it should be `head -n10`. I edited.

Comment: @SLePort correct solution for the **same** timezones. :)

Comment: my date is in dd/mm/yyyy format, it sort in dd only, not all date

Comment: You should edit your question that shows a different format.